# Speeding up / making more efficient SQL

Tags: mysql

This is my exact SQL code, but it's very slow and I know it's terrible...

Is there another way to do this but faster?

```
UPDATE Customer SET Title = "MR", SurName = "Test", FirstName ="Bob", HomePostCode ="SW18" WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CxID FROM Production WHERE policy_number = "001C5T" AND member_number = "100" AND family_group = "000001" AND CxID > 0)
```

Thanks

Comment: have you set an index on columns named in the subselect?

Comment: Yes, they all have the relevant indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (untested)

```
UPDATE Customer c
JOIN Production p ON p.CxID = c.CustomerID
SET c.Title = "MR",
    c.SurName = "Test",
    c.FirstName ="Bob",
    c.HomePostCode ="SW18"
WHERE p.policy_number = "001C5T"
    AND p.member_number = "100"
    AND p.family_group = "000001"
    AND p.CxID > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

you can join the tables in the update, so there will be no subselect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
UPDATE customer 
SET Title = "MR", SurName = "Test", FirstName ="Bob", HomePostCode ="SW18" 
FROM customer    
inner join production on customer.customerID = production.cxid 
where policy_number = "001C5T" AND member_number = "100" AND family_group = "000001" AND CxID > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on krakover's answer, you can join the tables:

```
UPDATE Customer JOIN 
Production P ON (C.CustomerID = P.CxID) 
AND (P.policy_number = "001C5T") 
AND (P.member_number = "100") 
AND (P.family_group = "000001") 
AND (P.CxID > 0)  
SET C.Title = "MR", C.SurName = "Test", C.FirstName ="Bob", C.HomePostCode ="SW18"
```

Note, please double check the table aliases, dependant on your shema.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without JOIN:

```
INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerID, Title, SurName, FirstName, HomePostCode)
SELECT CxID, 'MR', 'Test', 'Bob', 'SW18'
FROM Production
WHERE policy_number = '001C5T' AND member_number = '100' AND family_group = '000001' AND CxID > 0
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Title = VALUES(Title), SurName = VALUES(SurName), FirstName = VALUES(FirstName), HomePostCode = VALUES(HomePostCode)
```

This would require you to have and SELECT at least one unique column. Which I asume CustomerID is.